# Shapely LineString and Polygon intersect?

Tags: python, shapely

here is my python code, it does not intersect and when I plot this in google map , I see the intersection. shapely.geometry is in Cartesian plane, how you are solving this?

```
l = "40.65:-114.07 40.21:-112.96 40:-112.66 39.4:-112.7 39.39:-113.28 39.68:-113.94 40.42:-114.26 40.6:-114.22"
    points = [[float(x) for x in c.split(":")] for c in l.split(" ")]
    print(points)
    polygon = Polygon(points)
    path = LineString([(42.049999,-96.25), (38.0880979565,-119.609216457)])
    if path.intersects(polygon):
        print("intersect")
```

[image: here is the intersection on google map]

here is my code for google map:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8393151

Answer (score 4):

With your solution:

```
print polygon.wkt
'POLYGON ((40.6499999999999986 -114.0699999999999932, 40.2100000000000009 -112.9599999999999937, 40.0000000000000000 -112.6599999999999966, 39.3999999999999986 -112.7000000000000028, 39.3900000000000006 -113.2800000000000011, 39.6799999999999997 -113.9399999999999977, 40.4200000000000017 -114.2600000000000051, 40.6000000000000014 -114.2199999999999989, 40.6499999999999986 -114.0699999999999932))'
path = LineString([(42.049999,-96.25), (38.0880979565,-119.609216457)])
print path.wkt
'LINESTRING (42.0499989999999997 -96.2500000000000000, 38.0880979565000004 -119.6092164570000023)'
```

The result in Google Maps is really meaningless (obtained image with the [OpenLayers](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) plugin of QGIS)

[image]

So, it seems to me that there is an inversion in the coordinates of the points:

```
 40.65 is the latitude of the point -> y
 -114.07 is the longitude of the point -> x
```

and

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
l = "40.65:-114.07 40.21:-112.96 40:-112.66 39.4:-112.7 39.39:-113.28 39.68:-113.94 40.42:-114.26 40.6:-114.22"
# swapping the coordinates:
points = [[float(x) for x in c.split(":")[::-1]] for c in l.split(" ")]
print points
[-114.06999999999999, 40.649999999999999], [-112.95999999999999, 40.210000000000001], [-112.66, 40.0], [-112.7, 39.399999999999999], [-113.28, 39.390000000000001], [-113.94, 39.68], [-114.26000000000001, 40.420000000000002], [-114.22, 40.600000000000001]]
polygon = Polygon(points)
path = LineString([(-96.25,42.049999), (-119.609216457,38.0880979565)])
path.intersects(polygon)
False
```

I can plot the geometries in Google Maps and I see no intersection:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply: 

here is my code for google map:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8393151

it does show an intersection. 

how you are plotting this on google map?

Comment: How to find coordinates of intersection?